# pandas - reading column as float, converting invalid entries

Tags: python, regex, pandas

```
max_gust_speed = data[(data['Spd of Max Gust (km/h)'].astype(float) >= 50.0)]
```

Most data in this column is an integer or float. However, there are some other values (like the string '<32')

Is it possible to deal with these edge cases in this line, or do I need to go through the dataframe beforehand and convert these?

Can I coerce in this line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using @sacul's sample data (Thx)

You can use `replace` to strip non-numbery characters

```
g = 'Spd of Max Gust (km/h)'
n = pd.to_numeric(df[g].replace('[^\.\d-]', '', regex=True))
df[n >= 50]

  Spd of Max Gust (km/h)
0                     75
1                   80.2
```

Here, we preserved 32 from '<32'.  This may or may not have been what OP intended.  But this is how you do it.

And, `n` looks like

```
n

0    75.0
1    80.2
2    12.0
3    32.0
Name: Spd of Max Gust (km/h), dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want to do with it, but you can use `pd.to_numeric()` with `errors = 'coerce'`. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Spd of Max Gust (km/h)':[75, 80.2, 12, '<32']})

  Spd of Max Gust (km/h)
0                     75
1                   80.2
2                     12
3                    <32

>>> pd.to_numeric(df['Spd of Max Gust (km/h)'], errors='coerce')
0    75.0
1    80.2
2    12.0
3     NaN
```

So to apply your filter:

```
df[(pd.to_numeric(df['Spd of Max Gust (km/h)'], errors='coerce').astype(float) >= 50.0)]
```

Gives you this:

```
  Spd of Max Gust (km/h)
0                     75
1                   80.2
```